# How to get the number of characters in a JTextField?

Tags: java, swing, character, jtextfield

Is there a event on how to count the inputted character in a `JTextField`?

Comment: What do you mean by "number of strings"? Do you mean how many different words there are?

Comment: Please provide some of your code! What did you try? We can't help if we do not know what exactly your problem is. If you don't know how to ask properly, please refer to [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: There will be one string, and one string only.

Comment: `string.length()` ?

Comment: get the text using `String input = textfield.getText();` then use the length attribute of the string, `int count = input.length;`

Comment: Thank you arthur. Its number of characters inputted

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the method [getText()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getText()) inherited from JTextComponent to retrieve the current string value of your field (depending on your context, be prepared for NullPointerExceptions).

And then you can ask that string for the number of characters; using [String.length()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length()) to return the number of Unicode code points in that string.

If you are interested in counting *words* inside that string, you can use [String.split()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) in order to have that one string sliced into an array of sub-elements of it (for example using " " as argument, or "\s+" which splits on *any* wildcard).

Answer (score 2):

To get the text from your text field, call `getText()` on it. This will give you a String object with the text from the text field in it.

From there, if you want to get the number of characters in your text field, you can call the `length()` method on the String from the text field. `string.length();`.

If you want the number of words, use `string.split(" ").length;`, where `string` is the string from your text field object. This will split the string into a string array with each new word as an element of the string and then count how many elements there are.

Answer (score 2):

```
       String s = " ";
        char c = s.charAt(0);
 public static int countOccurrences(String haystack, char c)
        {
            int count = 1;
            for (int i=0; i < haystack.length(); i++)
            {
                if (haystack.charAt(i) == c)
                {
                     count++;
                }
            }
            return count;
        }
```